# Java not converting epoch correctly

Tags: java, epoch

I'm trying to convert the following epoch time

1382364283

When plugging this into an online converter it gives me the correct results.

10/21/2013 15:00:28

But the following code

```
    Long sTime = someTime/1000;
    int test = sTime.intValue();  // Doing this to remove the decimal

    Date date = new Date(test);
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    String formatted = format.format(date);

    this.doorTime = formatted;
```

Returns

16/01/1970 17:59:24

I've tried several other ways to convert this, is there something I'm missing?

Comment: What is `sometime`? How is it defined and assigned its value?

Comment: What is the purpose of calling sTime.intValue()? A long can only store an integer.... By casting to integer, you potentially cause an overflow which messes up your result. And java time is in **milliseconds**, unless your input time is in microseconds, you should be multiplying by 1000 not dividing by it.

Comment: Are you using `java.util.Date`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An epoch time is a count of seconds since epoch. You are dividing it by one thousand, gettings the number of thousands of seconds, that is, kiloseconds. But the parameter that `Date` takes is in milliseconds. Your code should be:

```
    long someTime = 1382364283;
    long sTime = someTime*1000;  // multiply by 1000, not divide

    Date date = new Date(sTime);
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    String formatted = format.format(date);

    System.out.println(formatted); // 21/10/2013 10:04:43
```

I don't get exactly your result, but I get the same results as online converters I tried.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor Date(long time) takes a time in millis ! As you divide your someTime (which is probably in millis) by 1000, you get time in seconds instead of millis.